# Transferring Python code from Sublime Text to Visual Studio code

Tags: sublime-text, visual-studio-code

When I transfer code (copy, paste) from Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code I get indentation errors while indentation looks fine. Even if I delete the indentation and retype it in Visual Studio Code I still get the indentation errors.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without knowing the details (e.g. which third-party packages do you use, which default indentation settings). You didn't even mention *how* the indentation differs across editors.

However, I generally recommend using [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/), which lets you define indentation rules (among others) for a project. About every major editor supports EditorConfig through plugins (including [Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EditorConfig) and [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig)). It's especially useful for teams that use a variety of different editors.

For Python, the Django [`.editorconfig`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/.editorconfig) file is a good starting point. Place it in the root of your project and now all editors with EditorConfig support will respect those rules.